# promise.then() returns Promise { <pending> }

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, async-await, es6-promise

Function fetchData returns a promise and then I'm dealing with that promise in generateURL function by chaining the `promise` with `.then` however it returns Promise < pending >. Function generateURL should return a string What am I doing wrong?

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const fetchData = async () => {
  return await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
};

const generateURL = () => {
  const baseURL = 'https://cdn.test.com/';
  fetchData().then((res) => {
    const data = res.json();
    console.log('data', data);
    const id = data.id;
    console.log('id', id);
    const generatedURL = `${baseURL}${id}`;
    return generatedURL;
  });
};
```

Comment: `res.json()` returns a promise. You need to chain to the result with `.then()`. It's a common source of tripping people up. Using the async/await syntax in that function will make it cleaner.

Comment: `generateURL()` can not return a string since there is an asynchronous method generating that string

Comment: but by using async/await in that function will only generate another promise as it is always returns a promise?

Comment: Please check out the answers here (the first few are jquery-specific, the good answers are a bit further down): [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reduced your code by a bit instead of adding multiple promise resolution

```
  const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const everything = async () =>{
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    const {id} = await response.json();
    return `https://cdn.test.com/${id}`
}
everything().then((res)=>console.log(res));
```

Comment: Thanks. But why though?

Answer (score 1):

having a `return await` is an anti pattern https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-await

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const fetchData = () => {
  return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
};

const generateURL = () => {
  const baseURL = 'https://cdn.test.com/';

  return fetchData().then((res) => {
    const data = res.json();
    console.log('data', data);
    const id = data.id;
    console.log('id', id);
    const generatedURL = `${baseURL}${id}`;

    return generatedURL;
  });
};

generateURL().then(result =>{
console.log(result)

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add another `then()` for the get result of `json()` as you can see on document https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#common-usage

So, it can be like below:

```js
const generateURL = () => {
  const baseURL = 'https://cdn.test.com/';
   fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(data => {
      console.log('data', data);
      const id = data.id;
      console.log('id', id);
      const generatedURL = `${baseURL}${id}`;

      return generatedURL;
  });
};
```

If you still want to use `fetchData` function it doesn't need to be `async-await`, just return `fetch` because it already returns a Promise.